# angular2 application not appearing properly in mobile

Tags: iphone, angular

I have developed a single page application. that displays a search button and onOninit the component connects to a server using REST HTTP and gets some default options displayed in a tabular format.

When I access using desktop it appears properly.

If I start the app using http-server on IP and try to access it using iPhone, the table appears but the content is not showing.

how to debug this issue?

Comment: One problem I found out is that wherever I use binding that part is not working. So in the page I query to another server and the result I bind with div/ table. 

i tried to display the response to simple label. That is also not working.

i looked into log of web server it shows 

[Wed Apr 12 2017 14:13:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] "GET /undefined" Error (404): "Not found"

So looks like if request is coming from IPhone the angular 2 app is not able to make REST/ HTTP request to another server.?

Comment: May be that is the issue of Design not from Backend. Have you checked the same with Chrome mobile view in desktop? If not then check it first. May be you will get something

Comment: i checked. its appearing properly in mobile view.

Also I checked using chrome in iphone, It has same problem. The binded value is not showing.

Comment: Do I have to do something more to make binding work on mobile devices for angular 2 component?

Comment: found something strange. Now If I do something on desktop app it shows the same thing in mobile app and vice versa. If I do search in mobile it shows the same search string parallely on desktop as well.

And on touch of 'Search' the result also shows in desktop app. But the same is not visible on mobile.